# Use Authorization Filters or parameter loading to overload action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Our site has a complex administrative hierarchy with a a few behavioral splits. To best direct user traffic, I created Authorization filters called MangersOnly, AdminOnly, NonAdmins.

I envisioned using them in this way

```
[MangersOnly]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}


[AdminOnly]
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return redirectoaction("Index", "Admins");
}

[NonAdmins]
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return redirectoaction("Shouldntbehere", "Errors");
}
```

What I sadly discovered was that attributes don't act as overloads to my action methods.

This architecture is to avoid all the logic checks we have to do (if role this or that stay, else redirect to here or there...). The goal is to direct traffic to the action method who's authorize attribute won't fail.

Is there a way I can overload these methods (w/o changing their parameters or names), keeping this sweet (tho naive) architecture to channel users to?

Comment: You have a false understanding of Post actions.  Using HttpPost does not allow you to create identical methods.  You have to differentiate them, typically by accepting a model in the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# (and any other language I can think of) you can't have more than one method (MVC or not) with identical signatures (attributes are not part of the signature); so this approach cannot work.

How about generating the anchor links ()in the view) based on the permissions of the user e.g. IndexManager, IndexAdmin, etc and add the role based security as normal. The names `IndexManager` don't make sense here which would make me think more about what is the user doing, is that a better name for the action? Only you know your domain to answer this.

Or go with a base controller for common functionality and inherit for each security level behaviours.

You might also want to consider permission based filtering not role based, see http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/

Comment: I love the article. Your idea of changing nav links and encapsulating functionality speaks to much of what we're doing. But we're inevitably left with the Q of 'what if user hits a page they shouldnt?' The short answer is, they won't. The long answer is, O, create all the logic to redirect them to where they should be. So permissions based logic is the rule with us, but it doesn't cover all contingencies.

Comment: In the end, permissions doesn't absolve us of the protective logic in case an admin hits a manager uri. We make adjustments where-ever possible for role based considerations page-to-page. but in many cases, a page for a manager is just NOT for an admin and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If the application looks and feels so dramatically different from user to user, you can always utilize MVC areas. I have developed several applications where I've used this feature to, based on login, direct a user to a specific area and tailor all content access and delivery to specific user groups.

For instance, I had a website where there was one login, and depending on who you were (customer support or customer) you are directed to different areas which all use the same DAL logic to get information, but the controller can filter it given the area. This also made it really easy to separate marketing material from order servicing and other processing logic. I really like these articles:

MVC5 Areas - http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html

Redirect Based on Login - [ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity 2 Login redirect based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526536/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-2-login-redirect-based-on-user-role)