# Redirect users according to their Identity Role - ASP MVC 4 and 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity-2

Hi I have an ASP MVC Application that using the MVC 5 Identity Roles, for the sake of simplicity I have 2 Identity Roles ("Admin" and "Staff"). Users in Role Admin can access the Admin Panel where they can create another users, and Users in Staff Role can only access Staff View.
I have no problem in assigning users to roles and apply [Authorise] to Controllers.

I want to redirect Users users to their relative Views after success log ins, so if a user is in Admin role, get's automatically redirected to admin panel or view and if a user in staff page redirected to staff view.

How do I apply this in my Login Controller? Thanks

Comment: You can simply redirect the users to the corresponding actions depending on roles, after they log in successfully. Will that work for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526536/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-2-login-redirect-based-on-user-role/26527406#26527406

Answer (score 5):

If you're using UserManager and SignInManager (as per the default template) in your Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn(SignInViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            // Redirect to User landing page on SignIn, according to Role
            if ((UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "User")))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
            if ((UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Administrator")))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administrator");
            }
            return View(model);
        // etc below - code to taste
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View(model);
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return View(model);
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect them from your login action method. So the pseudocode would be like below.

```
            if (User.Role == "Admin")
            {
                //send him to Admin controller and index action
                return RedirectToAction("ActionName","Controllername"); 
            }
            else if (User.Role == "Staff")
            {
                //send him to staff controller and index action
                return RedirectToAction("ActionName","Controllername"); 
            }
            else
            { 
               // if neither role show default public page
               return RedirectToAction("ActionName","Controllername");
            }
```

The comments are just to give you idea, It might vary in your application

Comment: Here is a helpful link for similar issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526536/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-2-login-redirect-based-on-user-role?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
if(UserType.Admin)
{
            return RedirectToAction("HomeAdmin","Admin") // Admin Home
}
else if(UserType.Staff)
{
            return RedirectToAction("HomeStaff","Staff")//Staff Home
}
```

And in your action methods

```
[Authorize]// Use this to authorize
public ActionResult HomeStaff()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[That's how I solved it, I didn't find any UserType or User.Role as stated in above solutions]